# Potential AutoMapper issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am having problems with my drop down list. I have previously posted this: [DropDownList not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942068/dropdownlist-not-behaving-as-expected), but things have changed so I'm submitting again.

I have a view model that looks like this:

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries =
        new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value = "0", Text = "Select a country..."},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "US United States"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "AF Afghanistan"},
            ...
        }
}
```

and in my view .cshtml:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 detail-right">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LegalEntity.Address.Country.CountryId,
        new SelectList( Model.LegalEntity.Address.Country.Countries, 
            "Value", "Text",
            Model.LegalEntity.Address.Country.CountryId),
        new { @class = "form-control" })               
</div>
```

The drop down is populating with items as desired, and the correct address IDs appear to be being posted to the server. I think the problem is with AutoMapper. The code in the controller seems to be creating a new row in the country table for each country in the view model. What it is supposed to be doing is adding a value in the foreign key in the address table pointing to the appropriate address:

```
public ActionResult Create(SiteViewModel siteViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Site newSite = new Site();
        newSite = Mapper.Map<SiteViewModel, Site>(siteViewModel);
        newSite.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        _unitOfWork.SiteRepository.Insert(newSite);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I get AutoMapper to do this?

Mark

=== More information ===

My SiteViewModel has an AddressViewModel, like this:

```
public class SiteViewModel
{
    ...
    public virtual AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and my AddressViewModel looks like this:

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    ...
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public virtual CountryViewModel Country { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: you need to post the part of your `Site` class that pertains to the `Country`. Do you have any pre-defined mappings for `SiteViewModel->Site` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so im going to give this a go at answer this without all the information.

Basically you are mapping the CountryViewModel to the Country 'domain object' your ORM is expecting.

AutoMapping is essentially running

```
new Country { Property = @value };
```

and creating a new Country object which is not Attached to your ORM.  Your ORM is instead creating these objects in the database.

What you want to be doing instead is using the information in the ViewModel to query the database for the Country object in the database and using that within your site.   Similar to the following

```
public ActionResult Create(SiteViewModel siteViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Site newSite = new Site();
        newSite = Mapper.Map<SiteViewModel, Site>(siteViewModel);

        newSite.Address.Country = DbContext.Countries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == siteViewModel.Address.Country.CountryId);

        newSite.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        _unitOfWork.SiteRepository.Insert(newSite);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
        ...
    }
}
```

This actually raises the point that the original design of AutoMapper was not to support what you are attempting here.   It was to help support the projection of your data layer into view layer objects, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to map your country object, you only want to map the Country foreign key.  So you need to add an ignore rule to your AutoMapper mapping that ignores the Country object mapping.

You want to do this for any lookup objects that have navigational properties on your object.  You don't want to add new objects, just insert with an existing foreign key.

However, this assumes your view model maps closely to your entity model. You may need to flatten your CountryViewModel, ignore the SelectList and Text, and just map the CountryId to the CountryId Foreign key in your Site object.  If you're not using separate foreign key properties (ie, both a foreign key and a navigational property) then you will have to do some mucking about to add a Country object with Modified state, and then just map the Id.

It's hard to make a recommendation, since you haven't given us the information for the objects that matter here, ie the Site entity and Country entity.  Nor have you given us your AutoMapper mappings.